# Trying to aggregate data from multiple files in two distinct tables

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I just got started in PowerBI and I am generating two report files every month from Service NOW.
SLA's report and the Incident report. Eventually, these files have the naming INC_MM_YY.xls or SLA_MM_YY.xls.

I am trying to make the addition of the previous month's files without the need to add new data sources/edit the queries. It seems that it is possible using M language in the advanced query editor but seems a lot complicated since I have 0 experience with power query M.

Are there other ways?
Or in the case above. I can retrieve the folder data as a table and iterate over the files. But how to do that in the M language?

Thank you.

EDIT: Just to try to make it clear let's look at the table generated by the folder source.

We have the name of the file and it's path for each row.

So in pseudo code should be something like:

```
For (each row as n) {
    if (n.folderpath ends with "sla") {
       tablesla += load source n."folderpath" && n."filename"
    }
    else tableincident += load source n."folderpath" && n."filename"
}
```

It just seems not practical in powerquery :/ I could find how to make something similar to a for loop but very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can actually create two different sources, one for the folder with the SLA and another with the folder for incident. Just after combining and transforming the data from one of the folders. Still in the Query Editor, you just click New Source and the other folder data will combined in a different table.

With that you have two distinct tables and any time when you put a new file in one of the folders, hit refresh, the data will be added to the correct table.

Thank you guys.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the answer so that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try the [load from folder option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-combine-binaries), you can place each months files into a its own folder one for the SLA's and one for the Incidents. With the load from folder, it will go though each file and load it. So the next month, you add in Novembers data, refresh the dataset(s) and it will add it automatically.

The files need to be the same structure for it to work effectively, and it will load what it sees in the folder, so if you remove a file, Power BI will not retain it in the workbook, it only loads what it can see.

Other examples

https://powerbi.tips/2016/06/loading-data-from-folder/

https://insightsoftware.com/blog/power-bi-load-data-from-folder/

Hope that helps

Comment: Problem with this approach is that the data gathered will be only for the most recent file. And I wanted to aggregate the data from any files in the folder not only the most recent. 

Useful but not what I am trying to achieve, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you have 3 files in the folder, it will load the 3 files as one table. You add another file in the it will load all 4. What you seem to be doing in the pseudo code, you are doing with load from folder???

Comment: Just tested it here, following the tutorials in the link only loads the most recent data and one of the files. The second one only works for files with the same structure. I could combine both types from different months into a single file but they have different data/columns, some with the same name but for different purposes.

Comment: You will have two folders, one for each dataset, one folder for incidents, and the other for SLA's. So you set up two loads from folder data connections